# ClojureScript: Data-Sharing in JS-Objects

Tags: clojurescript

I have a question about shared instances after lists in ClojureScript have been converted with the `clj->js` command.

I have following code:

```
(def list '(1 (5 6 7) 3 4 5))

(def jslist1 (clj->js (pop list)))
(def jslist2 (clj->js (pop list)))
(.log js/console "js:")
(.log js/console (= (get jslist1 0) (get jslist2 0)))

(def cljlist1 (pop list))
(def cljlist2 (pop list))
(.log js/console "clj:")
(.log js/console (= (get cljlist1 0) (get cljlist2 0)))
```

If I run this code, I get the console output:

```
js:
false
clj:
true
```

I would have expected, that the JS object also references the same instance of the `(5 6 7)` array. Instead it seems to create a new one. Does anyone know, why this behaves differently than the clj list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the source for [`clj->js`](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/blob/d56309ec0b9603a34fe096df4fd2ae8247687213/src/main/cljs/cljs/core.cljs#L9561) you will see the code that applies to collections:

```
(coll? x) (let [arr (array)]
            (doseq [x (map clj->js x)]
              (.push arr x))
            arr)
```

A **new** JS [`array`](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/blob/d56309ec0b9603a34fe096df4fd2ae8247687213/src/main/cljs/cljs/core.cljs#L383) is created and the entire contents of the collection is copied over to the JS array - **every time** `clj->js` is invoked.

Presumably the array is a defensive copy to prevent the original ClojureScript list and its contents from being modified.

Answer (score 0):

I assume in Clojure world those two lists are equal, because those two variables hold the reference to the same object in memory. Pop returns a reference to the same object.

In Javascript world those two lists become Arrays, i.e. Objects, and are compared by the rules of Javascript. Two objects, even though they contain the same value, are not equal, because they are two different references, two different bits in memory.

Comment: Hmm no, in clojure `pop` together with lists returns the rest of the list - in this case `((5 6 7) 3 4 5)`. I know that clojure uses structural sharing to speed things up but as soon as I use `clj->js` the structural sharing seems to get lost.

Comment: This is exactly what I meant to say.